# Refreshing the cache asynchronously once a @Cacheable method is invoked in Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, java-8

I am looking for any available option to cache a service data and then refresh it POST every time the service is called ASYNCHRONOUSLY.

Something like:

1. Service is called for the first time. It is served and data is cached.
2. Service is called for the second time. Cached data is served and
   another service is invoked which operates asynchronously and updates
   the cache.

I have came across Spring's Cache Abstraction where I can configure 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' and annotate the methods to be cached with @Cacheable annotation. But this serves the request from cache every time a request to the cached service is made.
There is also @CachePut annotation but it forces the service to be called every time and then refresh and update the cache by actually invoking the service.

Any suggestions with examples will be appreciated. I have been stuck with this for a while. I am looking to achieve this via Caffeine.

Comment: I would use `guava` for this

Comment: Tried a shot, couldn't decode the documentation or a good example

Comment: what _exactly_ did not work? it is fairly trivial to work with guava cache.

Comment: After reading much about Caffeine, I have moved to Caffeine instead of Guava. I am now trying out the same. Let me edit the question.